# How to setup to give list and then status of individual application?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Here is the scenario:
User says "Application" then as user's date of birth, last 4 digit of SSN and last name for verification. After that, show list of applications. Now user should be able to enter any one of the application number and the bot should give more details about the same.

I have created intent to till the stage where user gets list of application, however not sure how can I setup such that user can enter just the application number and system provides more details about it.

I tried creating another intent, but that seems conflicting with previous intent to show list of application.

Any online example will be a great help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To configure a Dialogflow ES agent to offer a roster of applications and subsequently provide the status of a specific application, follow these steps:

Create an intent to handle the **user's initial request** for a list of applications. Define an entity to capture the application names. Partner your **intent** with training phrases. E.g. `Intent: ApplicationList` | `Training Phrases: "Application list"`

Make a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) that fetches the list of applications from your data source and prepares a response message and retrieve the list of applications and format it as a response to the user's query.

Create an **intent for application status** to capture the user's request for the status of a particular application. Include an entity to extract the application name. This allows Dialogflow to extract the application number from the user's input.

Implement application status retrieval. In the fulfillment webhook, process the user's request, fetch the status of the specified application from your data source, and generate a response message.

Test the agent by simulating user queries for both the list of applications and application status. Continuously refine the agent's training data, intents, and fulfillment logic to improve its performance.